# Sync from on premises AD to Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I am working on a project to migrate the Consumer faced application to the cloud.

Based on the pricing I prefer to use the Azure AD B2C tenant.

Tentative timeline for the Azure AD B2C GA ?

How can I sync/move the user object from On-premises AD to the Azure AD B2C tenant? Can we use Azure AD connect for this?

Comment: Can you please clarify if the user base of your application consists solely of your on-premise AD?

Comment: Hi Saraf, 
Yes , the user information is stored in On-premise AD. We have more that 600k existing users in On-premises.we need to move all the users to Azure B2C tentant . Any idea when AD B2C will be available ? which will help me to plan accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in this [FAQ](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-faqs/),

> Can I use Azure AD Connect to migrate consumer identities that are stored on my on-premises Active Directory to Azure AD B2C?
>
> No, Azure AD Connect is not designed to work with Azure AD B2C. We
>   will provide various migration options and tools out-of-the-box in the
>   future.

Answer (score 1):

With the (beta) MSAL library (https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet), you can add both B2C and your existing AD to your website, so both worlds (external customers in B2C and corporate users in AD) can login to the same site.

from: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/enterprisemobility/2016/03/31/microsoft-identity-at-build-2016/

- MSAL is a developer library that helps you to obtain tokens from MSA, Azure AD or Azure B2C for accessing protected resources – such as your own API, Microsoft’s API (such as the Microsoft Graph) and any other 3rd party choosing to protect their API with Microsoft identity.

Comment: In my case the existing user information is stored in On-Premises AD where I have to create a B2C tenant , integrate the Application , move the users to the B2C directory, testing,production deploying and decommission the on premises environment.

Comment: Most fields can be programmatically moved (by using the GraphAPI to insert the data in B2C. Moving the password will be the problem with this solution I guess, because you don't have it in clear text (which is a good thing from a security perspective).